# Trigger after insert calling method in class

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, trigger

Added a trigger which in turn calls a method in class but is failing. My error is:

> Apex trigger MyTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: MyTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'TJ000000dsWeuMAE': ()

My trigger code:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Task (after delete, after insert, after undelete, 
after update) {

    MyClass c = new MyClass();

    for (Task t : System.Trigger.new) {
        if (Trigger.isUpdate)
        {
            c.UpdateTask(t);
        }
        else if (Trigger.isDelete)
        {
            c.DeleteTask(t);
        }
        else
        {
            c.AddTask(t);
        }
    }
}
```

My class code:

```
global with sharing class MyClass {

    Interaction_Summary__c intSum;

    private string query;
    private string filterClause;
    private string filterClause1;
    private string filterClause2;

    global MyClass()
    {       
        if(!Test.isRunningTest())
        {
            filterClause1 = MyCustomSetting__c.getValues('MyProperty').Filter_Clause_1__c;
            if (filterClause1 != null && filterClause1 != '')
            {
                filterClause2 = MyCustomSetting__c.getValues('MyProperty').Filter_Clause_2__c;
            }
            else
            {
                filterClause1 = '';
                filterClause2 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    global void AddTask(Task t)
    {   
        if (t != null)
        {
            intSum = new Interaction_Summary__c();
            PopulateInteractionSummary(intSum, t);
            if (filterPass(t))
            {
                Schema.SObjectField upsertField = Interaction_Summary__c.Related_To_Id__c;
                Database.upsert(t, upsertField, false);
            }
            else
            {
                DeleteTask(t);
            }
        }
    }

    global void UpdateTask(Task t)
    {
        //add code
    }

    global void DeleteTask(Task t)
    {
        //add code
    }

    global boolean FilterPass(Task t)
    {   
        string taskID = t.Id;
        filterClause = filterClause1 + ' ' + filterClause2;
        if(filterClause != null || filterClause != '')
        {
            query = 'Select Id from Task where id = ' + taskID + ' '  +  filterClause;
        }
        else
        {
            query = 'Select Id from Task where id = ' + taskID;
        }
        Task thisTask = Database.query(query);
        if (thisTask != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    global void PopulateInteractionSummary(Interaction_Summary__c intSum, Task t)
    {
        intSum.Related_To_Id__c = t.Id;
        intSum.IS_Subject__c = t.Subject;
        intSum.Type__c = 'Task';
        intSum.Related_To_Name__c = t.What.Name;
    }
}
```

Please help this salesforce newbie pinpoint the issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 query = 'Select Id from Task where id = \'' + taskID + '\'';
```

I think you missed enclosing the Id in single quotes.

Comment: So you agree with my duplicate vote basically. :)

Comment: Sorry didn't had a chance to look in to it that time. It's exactly the same and I completely agree :)